# How to pad vectors and matrices with 0s

Tags: r, matrix, vector

```
vec_length <- 4
nonzero_ind <- c(1, 3)
zero_ind <- c(2, 4)
```

**Vector:**

I currently have a vector called `vec` that contains 2 elements.

```
vec <- c(22, -5)
```

I want to obtain a vector of length `vec_length` that expands `vec` by adding 0s. The position of these 0s are specified by `zero_ind`. That is, I want a vector that looks like:

```
> expanded_vec
[1] 22  0 -5  0
```

**Matrix**

I currently have a 2x2 matrix called `mat` that corresponds to `vec`.

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
```

I want to obtain a `vec_length` by `vec_length` matrix where there are 0s in the (i,j)-th position if either i OR j is one of the `nonzero_ind`. That is, I want a matrix that looks like:

```
> expected_mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    2    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    2    0    3    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: You can get the vector with `"[<-"(rep(0,vec_length), nonzero_ind, vec)` or `"[<-"(rep(0,vec_length), seq_len(vec_length)[-zero_ind], vec)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the vector:

```
"[<-"(numeric(vec_length), nonzero_ind, vec)
#[1] 22  0 -5  0

"[<-"(numeric(vec_length), seq_len(vec_length)[-zero_ind], vec)
#[1] 22  0 -5  0

x <- numeric(vec_length)
(x[nonzero_ind] <- vec)
#[1] 22  0 -5  0

x <- numeric(vec_length)
(x[-zero_ind] <- vec)
#[1] 22  0 -5  0
```

and the Matrix:

```
i <- "[<-"(rep(NA,vec_length), nonzero_ind, seq_along(nonzero_ind))
mat <- mat[i, i]
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    2    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    2    0    3    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

or

```
mat_out <- matrix(0, vec_length, vec_length)
mat_out[nonzero_ind, nonzero_ind] <- mat
mat_out
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    2    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    2    0    3    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: `[<-` is a superb solution, efficient and concise, liked it +1!

Answer (score 0):

One example:

```
# Input data
vec_inp <- c(22, -5)
mat_inp <- matrix(c(1, 2, 2, 3), ncol = 2)


# Vector case
update_vec <- function(inp, len, nzi) {
  replace(x = vector(mode = 'double', length = len), list = nzi, values = inp)
}
update_vec(vec_inp, vec_length, nonzero_ind)
# [1] 22  0 -5  0

# Matrix case, work column by column
mat_out <- matrix(vector(mode = 'double', length = vec_length^2), ncol = vec_length)
for (i in seq_along(nonzero_ind)) {
  mat_out[, nonzero_ind[i]] <- update_vec(mat_inp[, i], vec_length, nonzero_ind)
}
mat_out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    2    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    2    0    3    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `kronecker` like below

```
> kronecker(vec,c(1,0))
[1] 22  0 -5  0

> kronecker(mat,matrix(c(1,0,0,0),nrow(mat)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    2    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    2    0    3    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```