# Count the number of types in the groups of data frame using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, counting, mutate

I have a data like this:

```
data<-data.frame(is.on=c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE"),
                 dur=c(10,20,30,10,10,10,10,20,10,20,30,40),
                 dt=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10),
                 block=c(2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,7),
                 interval_block=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4))
```

Now I want to make `summary_data` based on `block`.
The number of rows of `summary_data` is the number of types of `interval_block`.
step1:

```
# Step 1: Find the maximum number of types for block column within each interval_block
max_types <- sapply(unique(data$interval_block), function(interval) {
  blocks <- unique(data[data$interval_block == interval, "block"])
  length(blocks)
})
max_num_types <- max(max_types)
```

For `interval_block`=1, there is one type of block. (2)
For `interval_block`=2, there are three types of block. (3,4 and 5)
For `interval_block`=3, there are two types of block. (6 and 7)
For `interval_block`=4, there is one type of block. (7)
So the maximum number of types for `block` column within each `interval_block` is 3. And the above is the code to calculate that number. Based on this number, I want to make `dur_` columns. So, in this case, There should be `dur_1`,`dur_2` and `dur_3`.

Step2:
Decide the values of `dur_` columns.
For `interval_block`=1, there is one type of `block`.
I want to fill `dur_1` and leave `dur_2` and `dur_3` as 0.
#(`block`=2 within `interval_block`=1)=3. So, I want to fill `dur_1` as 3 times 10=30.

For `interval_block`=2,there are three types of `block`.
I want to fill `dur_1`, `dur_2` and `dur_3`.
#(`block`=3 within `interval_block`=2)=1,
#(`block`=4 within `interval_block`=2)=1,
#(`block`=5 within `interval_block`=2)=1.
So, I want to fill `dur_1` as 1 times 10=10, `dur_2` as 1 times 10=10 and `dur_3` as 1 times 10=10.

For `interval_block`=3,there are two types of `block`.
I want to fill `dur_1`, `dur_2` and leave `dur_3` as 0.
#(`block`=6 within `interval_block`=3)=2,
#(`block`=7 within `interval_block`=3)=1,
So, I want to fill `dur_1` as 2 times 10=20, `dur_2` as 1 times 10=10 and `dur_3` as 0.

For `interval_block`=4,there is one type of `block`.
I want to fill `dur_1` and leave `dur_2` and `dur_3` as 0.
#(`block`=7 within `interval_block`=4)=3.
So, I want to fill `dur_1` as 3 times 10=10, `dur_2` and `dur_3` as 0.

I described the rules quite long, but basically it is all about counting the number of types within `interval_block` and multiply to 10.
My expected output should look like this:

```
summary_data<-data.frame(dur_1=c(30,10,20,30),
                     dur_2=c(0,10,10,0),
                     dur_3=c(0,10,10,0),
                     interval_block=c(1,2,3,4))
```

I don't know how to code in R.

For clarification.
First row: there are 3 `block`=2 (one type). Sine one type, we fill only `dur_1` with 3 times 10.
Second row, there are 1 `block`=3 , 1 `block`=4 and 1 `block`=5 (three types). Since three types, we fill `dur_1`,`dur_2` and `dur_3` with 1 times 10, 1 times 10, 1 times 10 respectively.

Third row:
there are 2 `block`=6 , 1 `block`=7  (two types). Since two types, we fill `dur_1`,`dur_2` with 2 times 10, 1 times 10 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking advantage of {dplyr} and {tidyr}, you could do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data |>
  group_by(interval_block) |>
  mutate(ID = row_number(),
         dur = block |> as.factor() |> as.integer(),
         dur = 1 + dur - min(dur),
         dur_names = paste0('dur_', dur),
         dur_values = 10 * dur
         ) |>
  group_by(interval_block, dur_names) |>
  summarise(dur_values = sum(dur_values)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = dur_names, values_from = dur_values) |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x))) |>
  select(starts_with('dur'), interval_block)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   interval_block [4]
  dur_1 dur_2 dur_3 interval_block
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>
1    30     0     0              1
2    10    20    30              2
3    20    20     0              3
4    30     0     0              4
```

Edit:
a slightly esoteric alternative with base R:

```
data |>
  split(data$interval_block) |>
  Map(f = \(x) {
    max_blocks = with(data,  max(table(interval_block, block)))
    dur <- table(x$block)
    `[<-`(integer(max_blocks), seq_along(dur), 10 * dur)
  }) |>
  Reduce(f = rbind) |>
  cbind(unique(data$interval_block)) |>
  as.data.frame(row.names = FALSE) |>
  setNames(nm = c(paste0('dur_', 1:3), 'interval block'))
```

`'[<-'` for zero-padding taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65904017/how-to-pad-vectors-and-matrices-with-0s)

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of `base` R by first calculating a unique group block count then aggregate the data and reshape it to final format with cleanup:

```r
# ADD COLUMN FOR UNIQUE BLOCK GROUP NUM
data <- within(
    data, {
        dur_num <- ave(
            block,
            interval_block, 
            FUN=\(x) as.integer(factor(x))
        )
    }
) 

# AGGREGATE BY UNIQUE BLOCKS WITHIN INTERVAL BLOCK
agg_df <- aggregate(
    dt ~ dur_num + interval_block,
    data,
    FUN = sum
)

# RESHAPE WIDE
wide_df <- reshape(
    agg_df,
    idvar = "interval_block",
    timevar = "dur_num",
    v.names = "dt",
    direction = "wide",
    sep = "_"
)

# CLEAN UP
wide_df[is.na(wide_df)] = 0

row.names(wide_df) <- 1:nrow(wide_df)
colnames(wide_df) <- gsub(
    "dt_", "dur_", colnames(wide_df), fixed=TRUE
)


wide_df
  interval_block dur_1 dur_2 dur_3
1              1    30     0     0
2              2    10    10    10
3              3    20    10     0
4              4    30     0     0
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/F3ilbA6CjbL)</kbd>